Невозможно найти пакет create-expo-app@latest
~$ sudo apt install npx create-expo-app@latest
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет npx
E: Невозможно найти пакет create-expo-app@latest
Решил научиться создавать приложения. Посетил сайт React Native Expo(https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). Следуя инструкции(Чтобы создать новый проект Expo, запустите в своем терминале следующее:
npx create-expo-app@latest
После того как вы создали свое приложение, ознакомьтесь с остальной частью руководства по началу работы Expo, чтобы начать разработку своего приложения).
Невозможно найти пакет. Почему ? ОС-linux mint
